# Can I install packages from specific channels when using PIP as it's possible in Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

In Anaconda, there is the option of adding "channels" to the configuration files.

Every package installed with `conda install ...` will first look for packages in these channels (such as the `intel` channel, for instance).

Is there a way to make PIP also install from specific channels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` supports specifying additional repositories to look for packages; these behave similarly to channels in `conda<4`. Example:

```
$ pip install somepkg --extra-index-url http://myindex.org
```

Multiple additional indexes can be specified in `pip.conf`:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=
    http://myindex.org
    http://other-index.org
    http://third-index.org
```

When an index is provided via `extra-index-url`, `pip` will always search the default index at https://pypi.org, then the extra index and install the first matching package. Overriding http://pypi.org is also possible, via

```
$ pip install --index-url http://myindex.org
```

#### hosting a local index

It's actually pretty easy to host a local index if you need one. Although there are a lot of third-party PyPI servers available (to name a few: `devpi`, `wheelhouse` or `pypiserver`), you need nothing besides a Python installation to fire up one yourself. Create a directory with subdirs named same as packages and containing the installation files:

```
repo
└── MyPackage
     └── MyPackage.tar.gz
```

Navigate to the directory and run the stdlib's server:

```
$ cd repo/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000
```

Now you can install the packages from your local repository:

```
$ pip install MyPackage --extra-index-url = http://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

Comment: This is very very probably the answer, but how could I find the url for the channels used by anaconda? For instance, there is the `intel` channel (and only that, no address, no easy info on the internet)

Comment: I'm not much into `conda`, but AFAIR `conda info` should at least print all the URLs of channels used, but no name mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, I believe that `pip` doesn't have "channels" in the same way that Anaconda does. Essentially, `pip` assumes that for simple online installs (e.g. `pip install package_name`), it will be pulling from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

That said, regardless, it certainly is possible to pull from other sources (both local and remote) — see the [official Python installing packages guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs) for some examples. Supported sources can include version control systems (VCSs), alternate Indexes (i.e. not PyPI), local src tree, and local archives/wheels.

*More VCS support documentation for Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support)*.